# How to move a commit between branches?

Tags: git

I have this:

```
feature               D - E
                    /
develop   A - B   C
```

I want this instead:

```
feature           C - D - E
                /
develop   A - B
```

All commits are already pushed to github.  However, they are in my private fork only, so it is no drama if I'll have to rewrite history.

What's the cleanest and/or easiest way to move commit C out of develop, and rebase the feature?

Comment: `git checkout develop; git reset --hard HEAD^`

Comment: Minor, but still important, point: you can't move or change any *commit*, but you *can* change where a *branch name* points.  You aren't trying to move `C` at all—the two linear chains, `E` points-to `D` points-to `C` points-to `B` points-to `A`, remain the same either way.  You just need to have the name `develop` point to commit `B`, when it currently (pre-`reset`) points to `C`.  I think these drawings work better if you write the branch name just to the right of the commit, with an arrow from name to commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is reset develop to commit B.  C will be in the history of feature, and its predecessor will be the head of develop, so things will look the way your want them to.

Comment: Yep, since you're rewriting history (probably with a rebase) you'll have to do a force push.

Comment: yes-- force push develop sp the github branch will be in the right place.